Does the American government judge the severity of storms around whether Waffle House is still open?
During this stand up routine, it is claimed that the American government judges the severity of storms based on whether Waffle House is still open. I was just wondering how much of this video about Waffle House is factual.

I was in Atlanta a few weeks ago
and I went to a waffle house that didn't
have running water, and instead of closing they just gave me
a menu of things they could make without
water. I was like this is the consistency I
need.
This is so true that the the government
FEMA, Federal Emergency Management Agency, responsible for cleanup after disaster, is right - this is 100 true Google this when you
leave all right - has what's called a Waffle House index, okay,
and they determine how bad damage is in
an area after a storm by whether waffle
house is open or closed.
That's true, code green: waffle house is
serving full menu. Somewhere there's an
intern that frantically runs into an office
and says code red, and everyone in that room knows that waffle house is closed.


A good place to start might be the Wikipedia page about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffle_House_Index

When the first paragraph on Wikipedia tells everything, then "this question does not show any research effort".

@pipe That's not an issue.  https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

@Kyralessa It is absolutely an issue on skeptics where every simple "shower-question" can be turned into a question.

@pipe Please post a link to the site policy that specifically says that one has to have made some research effort on a question before posting it here.  ...Now if you want to debate whether something a stand-up comic says can be considered a notable claim, that's a different matter.

@Kyralessa It's right there in how to ask a good question

@Kyralessa My quote is copied literally from the downvote button popup: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

As mentioned in the video this is called the Waffle House Index, and the term was coined by former FEMA administrator Craig Fugate. It is not an official metric used by FEMA to determine the severity of a storm in the same way wind speed/rainfall/etc. are, however it is used informally to measure the health of a community after a disaster and to encourage disaster preparedness.
From a 2012 FEMA blog post:

What do Waffle Houses have to do with risk and disaster management?
As anyone who has heard Administrator Fugate speak once or twice knows, more than you might think. During his days as the head of Florida’s Department of Emergency Management, Craig began to use a simple test to determine how quickly a community might be able to get up and running again after a disaster: The Waffle House test.
If this comparison seems odd at first, think again.
Yesterday, EHS Today, a magazine for environment, health and safety leaders, explained that major companies such as The Home Depot, Walmart, and Waffle House serve as role models in disaster preparedness. They’ve taken necessary steps to prepare. These companies have good risk management plans to ensure that their stores continue to operate when a disaster strikes, and also provide basic supplies to people in their community.
...
As Craig often says, the Waffle House test doesn’t just tell us how quickly a business might rebound – it also tells us how the larger community is faring. The sooner restaurants, grocery and corner stores, or banks can re-open, the sooner local economies will start generating revenue again – signaling a stronger recovery for that community.

